# sampling distribution of covariance of two normal distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, estimation, covariance

Let $X$, $Y$ be two independent normal random variable, say $N(0,1)$. And I want to estimate $\operatorname{cov}(X,Y)$. What is the distribution of the $\widehat{\operatorname{cov}}(X,Y)$?

- Of course, I can calculate the true value directly with $\operatorname{cov}(X,Y)=0$.
- Suppose I have data $X_1,\cdots,X_n \sim N(0,1)$ and $Y_1,\cdots,Y_n \sim \text{ (another independent) } N(0,1)$
- Consider the estimator $\widehat{\operatorname{cov}}(X,Y)=\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-\bar{x})(y_i-\bar{y})$

Then my question is what is the distribution of $\widehat{\operatorname{cov}}(X,Y)$?

Comment: I did a simulation and the result is very similar to a normal distribution. Is is possible to prove that it is normal, with, like, CLT?

Comment: The normal distribution is about $N(0,(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}})^2)$.

Answer (score 0):

The answer seems to be given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wishart_distribution#Marginal_distribution_of_matrix_elements) (see $f(x_{12})$). Although I can't see the reference.

It's not quite as ugly as it seems -- it resembles the chi-square distribution, but is also modulated by a Bessel function. Note the simplification when $\rho = 0$, as in your question.